# Filling Array Allowed memory size of

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have about 150.000 Records in my table and I want to fill in my array and then I want to search in it, but because the data is too much I am getting

** PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes) in /home//.....// on line 21**

I am trying to fill in my array via this code

```
$myArray=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($myQueryName)){
    $myArray[$row['WordName']]=$row;
    echo $row['WordName'];
}
```

To avoid from that problem I think I can divide filling array into two or three like 
0 - 50.000 array 1 
50.000 - 100.000 array 2
100.000 - 150.000 array 3
then I will try to search in these 3 arrays.

How Can I solve it .

Comment: Err, perform your search via SQL??? Thats what a database is for

Answer (score 0):

I totally Advise against using the php script to search the database,use the database engine to search for that data , it's optimized for that.

If you want to change the memory limit that php uses for a script,you can set memory_limit in php.ini (In linux, php.ini is located in /etc/php/).

```
memory_limit = 128M // This will be global
```

If u want it per script use ini_set() method in the beginning

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
```